# What's the elegant way to spread subfigures on the multiple pages?

Tags: packages, subfloats

Having 3 figures that thematically should stay together in one `figure` environment as subfigures (I'm using `subfig` currently), I know that there's no way to **allow those pictures to separate** over few pages automatically with `subfig` (according to 13.pg of [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf)).

Is there a way to do this with some other package? **- OR -** What's the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\makeatletter\def\CT{\def\@captype{figure}}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\CT
\subfloat[My first subfig caption]{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{foo}}\quad
\subfloat[My second subfig caption]{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{foo}}

\subfloat[My third subfig caption]{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{foo}}\quad
\subfloat[My forth subfig caption]{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{foo}}

\subfloat[My fifth subfig caption]{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{foo}}\quad
\subfloat[My sixth subfig caption]{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{foo}}
\captionof{figure}{My caption for all subfigures together}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could someone please explaing why this triggers the wanted behaviour?